# Oracle Import Error - Field Length

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, set, character

I'm running into errors when trying to import a table from a western character set into UTF character set. I know the problem is that some of the data "grows". F

For example:

```
ORA-02374: conversion error loading table "RESULT"
ORA-12899: value too large for column MATRIX_NAME (actual: 11, maximum: 10)
ORA-02372: data for row: MATRIX_NAME :
```

I know originally when the backup was done in the source database (which uses Western English character set), that column field length is defined as varchar(10), however when imported into target database (uses UTF character set), the data grows to length of 11.

Does Oracle have a way to automatically fix the field length (so it expands the field length automatically into 11), before it imports the data, so to ensure there is no truncating of the data. How to do it?

I'm using Oracle 11G.

Comment: it was defined as 10 bytes in source database, the target schema is empty.

Comment: Ha, for some reason I thought this was for SQL*Loader, sorry. Are you using exp/imp or expdp/impdp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Oracle's built-in import / export tool can automatically handle size issues.

Comment: Anyone knows specifically how to, have import tool autoamtically expand column to fit the data that's grown?